# How to utilise GNU parallel efficiently?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, resources, gnu-parallel

I have a script say `parallelise.sh`, whose contents are 10 different python calls shown below:

```py
python3.8 script1.py
python3.8 script2.py
.
.
.
python3.8 script10.py
```

Now, I use GNU parallel
`nohup parallel -j 5 < parallellise.sh &`

It starts as expected; 5 different processors are being used and the first 5 scripts, `script_1.py ... script_5.py` are running. Now I notice that some of them (say two of them `script_1.py` and `script_2.py`) complete very fast, whereas the others need more time to complete.

Now, there are unused resources (2 processors) while waiting for the remaining 3 scripts (`script_3.py, script_4.py`, and `script_5.py`) to complete so that the next 5 can be loaded. Is there a way to use these resources by loading new ones as existing commands get completed?

For information: My OS is CentOS

Comment: Regarding your first concern, yes my bad, I had a typo, so I was using a redirect in the middle; edited now.

Comment: Ah! Much better. Then there is nothing else to do. `parallel` takes care of always running 5 jobs. As soon as one finishes a new one is launched. It does not wait until the 5 first jobs finish before launching the 5 next. Why do you think it does so?

Comment: For some reason, it didn't load the new jobs. I am running again using `-a` this time, will confirm here if it works this time and close the question. Rather I will test again with `-a` and once with `>`; If there is a difference in the results, I will add it in the question and edit the question accordingly/. If it was due to some wrong observation I made, I will write an apology here and delete the question! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @RenaudPacalet says there is nothing else to do.

So there is something in your scripts which causes this not to happen.

To help debug you can use:

```
parallel --lb --tag < parallellise.sh
```

and maybe add a "Starting X" line at the beginning of scriptX.py and a "Finishing X" line at the end of scriptX.py so you can see that the scripts are indeed finishing.

Without knowing anything about `scriptX.py` it is impossible to say what is causing this.

(Instead of `nohup` consider using `tmux` or `screen` so you can have the jobs run in the background but always check in on them and see their output. `nohup` is not ideal for debugging).